# Проблема при открытии формы в Qt creator

Tags: qt, ооп, qt5, qtcreator, forms

примерно месяц назад установила Qt creator на windows 10. Все работало хорошо.
На днях запускаю приложение открываю проект и при запуске форм mainwindow.ui он зависает а потом вылетает сам qtcreator и больше ничего, без каких либо окон, ошибок. Запускаю заново, при создании нового проекта происходит тоже самое. Попробовала все обновить, переустановить, удалить полностью без всяких зависимостей, снова установить, все тоже самое, можно создавать проект, компилировать, даже нашела старый проект с графическим интерфейсом скомпилировала, все кнопки, все правильно работает, а при открытии редактора форм все равно вылетает

у какого-нибудь были проблемы с формами в qt кто знает, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: запустите из консоли кретатор, что в логах пишет после вылета?

Comment: Была такая проблема.Решил удалением временных файлов Qt Creator

Comment: Первое - почистить временные файлы, второе - если вы создавали и внедряли в форму кастомные виджеты, то проверить их конструкторы/деструкторы

Answer (score 0):

возможно косяк с настройками qt creator. Самое простое - удалите полностью Qt, затем удалите полностью каталоги с настройками: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\QtProject и C:\Users\\AppData\Local\QtProject

После этого пробуйте ставить заново